# Is there a better way to parse String resources for a large Android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I am making an app for studying Chinese. Each lesson contains ten TextViews within a Scrollview, and I plan on there eventually being 500 lessons in all. Changing the lesson changes the text of each respective TextView. Here are screenshots of the first two lessons.

[image]

[image]

I am storing all of my sentences for the entire course inside a one-dimensional array in my strings.xml resource file.

```
<array name="course">
    <!--Lesson 1-->
    <item name="l1s1">好。Hǎo. Good, okay.</item>
    <item name="l1s2">不好。Bù hǎo. Not good, not okay.</item>
    <item name="l1s3">好不好？Hǎo bù hǎo? Okay?</item>
    <item name="l1s4">很好。Hěn hǎo. Very good.</item>
    <!--LOTS MORE LESSONS AND ITEMS HERE-->
</array>
```

I would have liked to use a two-dimensional array for the entire course with a sub-array for each lesson, but I get a "Failed to compile values file." error message when I try to run my program in Android Studio. It appears that only one-dimensional arrays are allowed here, so this is how I parse the strings.xml file programmatically within the onCreate() method.

```
sentenceArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.course);
sentenceList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sentenceArray));
lessonList = new ArrayList<>();
numberOfSentences = sentenceList.size();
numberOfLessons = numberOfSentences / 10;
lessonNumber = 1;

//populates lists of lessons and sentences from strings.xml
//note that all lessons must contain exactly ten sentences
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLessons; i++) {
    List<String> lesson = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        lesson.add(sentenceList.get(index));
        index++;
    }
    lessonList.add(lesson);
}
```

Meanwhile, I created a separate updateLesson() method in my MainActivity class to change the text of each TextView whenever the user selects a new lesson.

```
public void updateLesson(int lessonNumber) {
    if(lessonNumber < 1) lessonNumber = 1;
    else if(lessonNumber > numberOfLessons) lessonNumber = numberOfLessons;
    String text = getString(R.string.lesson_number) + lessonNumber + " " + getString(R.string.of) + " " + numberOfLessons;
    textView.setText(text);

    textView1.setText(sentenceList.get((lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView2.setText(sentenceList.get(1 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView3.setText(sentenceList.get(2 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView4.setText(sentenceList.get(3 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView5.setText(sentenceList.get(4 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView6.setText(sentenceList.get(5 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView7.setText(sentenceList.get(6 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView8.setText(sentenceList.get(7 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView9.setText(sentenceList.get(8 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
    textView10.setText(sentenceList.get(9 + (lessonNumber - 1) * 10));
}
```

This works okay for now, but I do not think it will scale well when there are hundreds or thousands of lines in strings.xml. Plus, there is no flexibility for if I want to make lessons of varying lengths. Also, I would really like each sentence in my course to be its own array so I can allow the user to choose between Simplified/Traditional characters, Mandarin/Cantonese pronunciation and English/Spanish translation. What I really need is a three-dimensional array like this:

```
<array name="course">
    <array name="lesson1">
        <!--PRIOR ITEMS OMITTED-->
        <array name="l1s6">
            <item name="l1s6simplified">你好吗？</item>
            <item name="l1s6traditional">你好嗎？</item>
            <item name="l1s6mandarin">Nǐ hǎo ma?</item>
            <item name="l1s6cantonese">Nei5 hou2 maa1?</item>
            <item name="l1s6english">Are you well?</item>
            <item name="l1s6spanish">¿Está bien?</item>
        </array>
        <!--REMAINING ITEMS OMITTED-->
    </array>
    <!--REMAINING LESSONS OMITTED-->
</array>
```

Of course, Android Studio will not even allow a 2D array, let alone a 3D one. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest store the strings in chunks e.g. `lesson1.txt`, `lesson2.txt` and so on in the `assets` folder. This way, you're using less memory than your current approch.

Comment: @Darkman Thanks. I am not entirely sure how I would be able to access the strings that way, but I will look into it.